# Installing Postgres App on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, debian, linux-mint, postgresql

I've been put on a web app project that is built using Ruby on Rails and uses PostgreSQL for the database. All the other developers on the team have Macs so they just installed [Postgres app](http://postgresapp.com/) to set up their development environment. Unfortunately for me, that app is not supported by Linux. I'm running Linux Mint and need to set up my dev environment like Postgres App does for the Mac. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `apt-get install postgresql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `postgresql` package is avaible on linux mint repo

```
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql
```

Also can use the [PostgreSQL Apt Repository](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/), there is an example (linux-mint 18):

```
sudo sh -c \
'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main" > \
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'

wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | \
sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-9.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting up your dev environment with docker. The official docker website has a step-by-step tutorial for rails-postgres installation.

In short, you just need to add `Dockerfile` and a `docker-compose.yml` to your rails project followed by a `docker-compose up` command. This will ensure that you have you local environment is up and running without having to manually setting up ruby/gems/postgres.

[Docker-Rails-Postgres](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/)