# Install Postgres database on FreeBSD

Tags: software-installation, freebsd, postgresql, bsd

How does one go about discovering and installing the [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) database system onto a [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD) machine?

Must one install the entire gig of data for the entire [Ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_Ports) tree, and then compile from source? I know there are many compile-time options available for Postgres, but I am willing to go with all the defaults.

➥ Is there a way to install a prebuilt binary for FreeBSD running on an [AMD64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/x86-64) system?

I am interested in both the final release versions as well as beta versions of Postgres. I see neither Beta 1 nor B[eta 2 of Postgres 12](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1949/) listed in the [Ports page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=postgresql&stype=all&sektion=all).

I am used to using a simple installer-app for installing Postgres on a Mac. Are there complications to installing on a Unix system such as FreeBSD that I need to be aware of?

This Question here is the same as [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321667/56752) but for FreeBSD rather than Linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install only a portion of the Ports tree in FreeBSD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/530014/install-only-a-portion-of-the-ports-tree-in-freebsd)

Comment: @arrowd Postgres is a large complicated system with many parts, not a simple app. I expect there are many Postgres-specific issues with regard to installation. So this is a distinct Question from [that one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/530014/install-only-a-portion-of-the-ports-tree-in-freebsd).

Comment: As always, the answer is in [The Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports.html)

Answer (score 2):

`pkg` is your friend here. `man pkg` for more info.  You may already have some binary packages installed on your system.  `pkg info` will tell you what packages (if any) are installed.  On a freshly-installed system, `pkg info` will tell you that `pkg` is not yet installed, and ask whether you would like to install it:

```
root@test:/root # pkg info
The package management tool is not yet installed on your system.
Do you want to fetch and install it now? [y/N]: y
Bootstrapping pkg from pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/FreeBSD:12:amd64/latest, please wait...
Verifying signature with trusted certificate pkg.freebsd.org.2013102301... done
[test] Installing pkg-1.11.1...
[test] Extracting pkg-1.11.1: 100%
pkg-1.11.1                     Package manager
```

Once you have installed `pkg` you can search for the version of PostGreSQL you would like:

```
# pkg search postgres
```

That gives 78 results, so you may want to use `grep` to show only the packages that embody a full PostgreSQL server:

```
# pkg search postgres | grep '^postgresql.*-server'
postgresql10-server-10.6_2     PostgreSQL is the most advanced open-source database available anywhere
postgresql11-server-11.1       PostgreSQL is the most advanced open-source database available anywhere
postgresql94-server-9.4.20_2   PostgreSQL is the most advanced open-source database available anywhere
postgresql95-server-9.5.15_2   PostgreSQL is the most advanced open-source database available anywhere
postgresql96-server-9.6.11_2   PostgreSQL is the most advanced open-source database available anywhere
```

If you want beta versions, then yes, you probably will have to install from source.

Comment: One problem: I have found neither Beta 1 nor [Beta 2 of Postgres 12](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1949/) listed on the [Ports page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=postgresql&stype=all).